# Electrochemistry lye quality

Tags: electrochemistry

With the following setup: plastic container, water (impure), pencil (anode), tin foil (aluminum, cathode) and solar panels supplying electrical charge (roughly 36v at about 400-800ma), with the intention of producing lye via electrochemistry:

1) Would it be possible to produce the right kind of lye to a level sufficient to produce handsoap with this current setup?

2) How would you test the lye quality to be sure?

If not possible to make the right quality lye, is there a way to modify the setup so it's able to produce suitable quality lye for soapmaking?

Comment: You can purchase Red Level lye in a supermarket.

Comment: A common way outside the lab to test if the strength of the lye before soap-making is to put an uncooked egg in the lye; if around 1/4 inch sticks out floating at the top, it's fine

Comment: @UncleAl I want to see if I can produce reasonable quality lye for free.

Comment: @UncleAl Also if you mean "red devil" lye, it's apparently been discontinued: http://candleandsoap.about.com/b/2005/09/19/its-not-a-lye.htm

Comment: http://www.essentialdepot.com/servlet/the-Sodium-dsh-Hydroxide-dsh-Lye-dsh-Food-dsh-Grade/Categories
http://www.essentialdepot.com/servlet/the-Sodium-dsh-Hydroxide-dsh-Lye-dsh-Tech-dsh-Grade/Categories

Comment: Knowledge would be a better reward than convenience for me.

Comment: I'm quite curious if you had any success @user4838. But in my opinion, power from power network would be better than power from solar panels.